# Opened Safari by pressing a button, how i can come back to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am new to iOS and objective C. I have to create a simple app where user will press a button and as a result, app will open safari. Then user have to come back to my app again. I have opened safari but I don't know how to bring user back to my app. I have used this simple code:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Any suggestion that how I can do that?

Comment: I think this can't be archived if the redirection isn't back in your app.

Comment: You will need to use Custom URL scheme for that..

Comment: I have read about custom URL schemes but unable to use it.

Comment: Does any answer fit your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a URL using

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Your OS takes care of loading a new application. Instead if you wanna load a web URL use apple's `UIWebView` class.

Comment: I cannot use UIWebView

Comment: But what is the advantage of going to safari over webview?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this, only on your own urls following this:

First of all you want a custom scheme. https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"http://www.yourserver.com/file.php"]];
```

Now because the url is point at your own server you can redirect using the scheme that you create eg. `myapp://`.

In your server, in file.php if you set this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">location.href="myapp://"</script>
```

Then will came back in your app.

Comment: I think it can't be done this. Anyone correct me if iam wrong. In fact it must have a trigger for this. How google will trigger this and came back to your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the page you are sending them to, no you can't do this.

If you want to remind them to come back, you could schedule a [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to appear a few seconds after opening the URL - if they touch this they will be brought back into your app. This will pop up on screen as an alert or a banner depending on the current user preferences.

Comment: But that can irritate user if he is not finished yet and don't want to come back to app.